# What is VC keymap?

Tags: systemd, keyboard-layout, locale

Here is what I get when executing `localectl status`:

```
$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us-acentos
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc104
     X11 Variant: us-intl
```

What is the VC Keymap? What is the difference between that and the X11 Variant?

Comment: It’s the keymap for the virtual console, hence **VC**. See
``vconsole.conf(5)``.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The VC is the *virtual console* which is also known as a *virtual terminal* VT. It is the full screen tty you might see before X11 launches (or switch to with Ctrl+Alt+2). It has its own keymap architecture but systemd has merged the setting of X11 and VT keymaps into one command "for convenience".

See commands like `chvt`, `openvt`, `loadkeys` and `man 4 console`.